# Proper config for Unity dependency resolver to work with MvcMembership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, asp.net-membership, unity-container

I am not able to find the proper Unity configuration to get it to work with MvcMembership.

At this point, I am getting the following error message:

> The type Boolean cannot be constructed. You must configure the
>   container to supply this value.

Here is my code to register dependencies:

```
    container.RegisterInstance<MembershipProvider>(Membership.Provider);

    container.RegisterType<IMembershipSettings,AspNetMembershipProviderSettingsWrapper>();
    container.RegisterType<IUserService, AspNetMembershipProviderWrapper>();
    container.RegisterType<IPasswordService, AspNetMembershipProviderWrapper>();
    container.RegisterType<IRolesService, AspNetRoleProviderWrapper>();
    container.RegisterType<ISmtpClient, SmtpClientProxy>();
    container.RegisterType<IRegistrationSettings, RegistrationSettings>();
```

And here is my Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: The type Boolean cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.]
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.GuardTypeIsNonPrimitive(IBuilderContext context, SelectedConstructor selectedConstructor) +277
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +485
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +434
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlanCreatorPolicy.CreatePlan(IBuilderContext context, NamedTypeBuildKey buildKey) +400
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +222
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +434
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +318
   BuildUp_MvcMembership.Settings.RegistrationSettings(IBuilderContext ) +216
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +304
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +434
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +318
   BuildUp_MvcMembership.Settings.AspNetMembershipProviderSettingsWrapper(IBuilderContext ) +220
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +304
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +434
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +318
   BuildUp_MyProject.Web.Areas.MvcMembership.Controllers.UserAdministrationController(IBuilderContext ) +223
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +304
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +434
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +440

[ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MyProject.Web.Areas.MvcMembership.Controllers.UserAdministrationController", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.

### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type Boolean cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving MyProject.Web.Areas.MvcMembership.Controllers.UserAdministrationController,(none)
  Resolving parameter "membershipSettings" of constructor MyProject.Web.Areas.MvcMembership.Controllers.UserAdministrationController(MvcMembership.Settings.IMembershipSettings membershipSettings, MvcMembership.IUserService userService, MvcMembership.IPasswordService passwordService, MvcMembership.IRolesService rolesService, MvcMembership.ISmtpClient smtpClient)
    Resolving MvcMembership.Settings.AspNetMembershipProviderSettingsWrapper,(none) (mapped from MvcMembership.Settings.IMembershipSettings, (none))
    Resolving parameter "registration" of constructor MvcMembership.Settings.AspNetMembershipProviderSettingsWrapper(MvcMembership.Settings.IRegistrationSettings registration, MvcMembership.Settings.IPasswordSettings password, MvcMembership.Settings.ILoginSettings login)
      Resolving MvcMembership.Settings.RegistrationSettings,(none) (mapped from MvcMembership.Settings.IRegistrationSettings, (none))
      Resolving parameter "requiresUniqueEmailAddress" of constructor MvcMembership.Settings.RegistrationSettings(System.Boolean requiresUniqueEmailAddress)
        Resolving System.Boolean,(none)
]
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +546
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +68

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyProject.Web.Areas.MvcMembership.Controllers.UserAdministrationController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +634403
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +93
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +346
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass6.b*_2() +71
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +161
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +405
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by specifying which constructor to use for UserAdministrationController using the following attribute above the said constructor:

```
[Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionConstructor]
```

When a constructor is overloaded, Unity tries to use the one with the most arguments. Using the InjectionConstructor attribute, I forced it to use the constructor taking zero argument.

Comment: Might've helped you in your situation. I had 2 controller constructors I was switching back & forth between, as well. Did not help me to give the one I wanted your attribute you listed, here. The reason for my issue? In my repository class I had a `[Dependency]` attribute on `public Model1 DbContext { get; set; }`. That wasn't getting resolved. I went with commenting that out & I had `private readonly Model1 context;` and `public DataRepository()
        {
            context = new Model1();
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }` which worked just fine.